# Get next post's permalink in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this code to get a link to the next post in Wordpress

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', '', TRUE); ?>
```

And it gives me this result:

```
<a href="http://www.someaddress.com/post/3/" rel="next"></a>
```

All I need is a URL like this:

```
http://www.someaddress.com/post/3/
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

**Previous Post:**

```
<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)); ?>
```

**Next Post:**

```
<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)); ?>
```

Comment: heytools, thank you very much
`<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)); ?>`
this code works!
is it possible to go back to first post after last one is reached?
i need only one direction link e.g. previous or next

Comment: Should I remove the 2nd part? In case you tried it and it doesn't work it's better removed.